# Pass a constexpr char[] var to template param of struct and then use fmt to output will throw an exception?

Tags: c++, exception, constexpr, fmt

example code

```
template<const char* str>
class MyStruct
{
public:
    void Print()
    {
        cout << fmt::format("{}", str);
    }
};

constexpr char szTest[] = "hello";

int main()
{
    MyStruct<szTest> info;
    info.Print();
    return 0;
}
```

In practice, This code throws an exception in function 'basic_string_view(const Char* s)', I tried to replace constexpr with const, and then everything is ok. Does anyone know why?

I want to know why constexpr cannot be used here, Is that the rule or a bug ?

More Info:

OS: Windows

IDE: vs2019 (16.11.18)

C++ Language Standard: C++20

Fmt version: 9.1.0 (The same problem exists with std::format)

Comment: Which compiler are you using? Both GCC and Clang [print "hello" here](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/88Yfjf6MP) while MSVC has a linker error.

Comment: Could be a bug. From dcl.constexpr:

"A constexpr specifier used in an object declaration declares the object as const."

Comment: Looks like msvc's linker bug.

Comment: I also can't reproduce your claimed behavior. Please add to the question: 1) Compiler you are using including version 2) compiler flags you are using 3) version of <fmt> you are using. Also complete the example. It is at least missing `#include` directives.

Comment: @user17732522 I think [this demo](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/TxjTTaKfY) shows the problem.

Comment: @JasonLiam That's not the problem OP claims to have though. And going by the `visual-studio-code` tag and the use of the fmt library instead of `std::format`, I suspect that they are not using MSVC.

Comment: @user17732522 The `vscode` tag might be a mistake by OP. Here is the new [bug](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/MSVC-rejects-program-involving-constexpr/10245388). Ofcourse the program is well-formed(since `szTest` is a valid template nontype argument here)

Comment: @JasonLiam On compiler explorer any call to `fmt::format` isn't working with MSVC. It is much more likely to be a misconfiguration on compiler explorer's side: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/TozWhdnb4. I don't have MSVC here to verify it myself though.

Comment: @user17732522 That is a possibility. Haven't checked it locally though.

Answer (score 1):

`szTest` is a valid template non type argument for a parameter of type `const char*` and the program is well-formed.

> Is that the rule or a bug ?

Yes, this seems to be a [msvc linker bug](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/MSVC-rejects-program-involving-constexpr/10245388). Both gcc and clang execute the program without any problem.

Comment: Your demo appears as link error, but i got a runtime error ? Is this my vs version problem?

Comment: Can you paste here the exact error you're getting. Just copy/paste the complete error message. Anyways, even so there is some problem here(which can be either in compiler explorer or msvc's linker)

Comment: It's an exception when i run the code with debug mode. The problem occurs in the strlen call in the basic_string_view(const Char* s) function.It cannot be caught by C++exceptions, so there is no specific error message. It looks like an error exists in the parameter str passed in by fmt:: format, because in the vs monitor, arg's value is displayed as' Error reading characters of string ', and when I use const instead of constexpr, in the vs monitor, arg's value is displayed normal.